# How to select all the object with same vertex count as the object selected in blender in Python

Tags: python, add-on, selection-tools

I am working on multiple files. Is there any way to select all the objects in the with exact same vertex count of the active objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
import bpy


def no_of_verts(obj):
    
    return len(obj.data.vertices)

active_object = bpy.context.object

no_of_vertices = no_of_verts(active_object)


for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    
    if no_of_vertices != no_of_verts(ob):
        print(ob, "deselected")
        ob.select_set(False)
    else:
        print(ob, "is ok")
```

Comment: working but I have to select all the objects.

Comment: replace with `for ob in bpy.context.selectable_objects: if not ob.type == "MESH": continue ob.select_set(no_of_vertices == no_of_verts(ob))`